# Exploring Apache Kylin cubes with Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, olap, mondrian, saiku, kylin

I had some conflicts with my teammates about if it is really the Power BI can read and explore Apache Kylin Cubes or it is just exploring the Data source,

I had some problems with saiku exactly in the Mondrian schema that's why I am using Power BI, I couldn't use Superset cause of the lack of time since i need to deliver the project in time.

I just want to do some data visualization from the cubes,

Is there any understandable documentation you guys can provide me?
I will really be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Cube API in Power BI. You could display Kylin defined tables in Power BI through ODBC driver. There are some commercial solutions for Kylin and Power BI. Check this: https://kyligence.io/resources/enable-interactive-big-data-analytics-of-power-bi/

Comment: Thank you for your response,But I am still confused about if the Power BI will use the Kylin defined tables I mean does the Power BI queries will be sent to the Hbase through Kylin or will it use the data source ?